# Proofing a Reachable Node Algorithm for Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, proof-writing

I am trying to proof the following algorithm to see if a there exists a path from u to v in a graph G = (V,E).

```
Reach := {u}
LastCardinality := 0
while LastCardinality < |Reach| do
  LastCardinality := |Reach|
  Next := null
  foreach i <- Reach do
    foreach j <- V do
      if(i,j) exists in E then
        Next := Next + {j}
  Reach := Reach + Next
return Reach
```

So far I have got that the output needs to be Reach = Goal where Goal = {r | r exists V, there is a path from u to r}. I also have three invariants that I am pretty sure will help prove this.

1. Reach is always a subset of Goal and Next is always a subset of Goal.
2. After an arbitrary K times through the while loop, for every t that exsits in V, if t has a path of length k+1 from u, then t exists in Reach
3. If Reach is a subset of Goal before the while loop then LastCardinality < |Reach|

I know that to finish up the proof, I need to prove termination, the invariants, and correctness but I have no idea how. I think I need to use induction on the while loop but I am not exactly sure how.

How do I proof those three characteristics about an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with termination. You have an initial set $Reach$. Since you are traversing a connected component of $G$ and (we are assuming) $G$ is finite, only a finite number of nodes can exist in $Next$. And so $Reach := Reach + Next$ will eventually not add any additional nodes to $Reach$.

A better way to put that. Suppose $Reach \subset V(X)$ and $Reach \neq V(X)$, where $X$ is the component we are on. Then there exists a vertex in $Reach$ with unvisited neighbors. Your inner for loop will visit those neighbors and add them to $Next$, which will then be added to $Reach$. Otherwise, if $Reach = V(X)$, then $Reach = Next$ after the set of nested for loops terminates. And so on the next iteration of the loop, $LastCardinality = V(X)$. As $Reach$ will not increase in cardinality, the while loop will terminate, and so the algorithm will terminate.

To prove correctness, you need to show two things. The first is if $u, v \in V(X)$, then $v \in Reach$ upon termination of the algorithm. The second is that if $v \not \in V(X)$ but $u \in V(X)$, then the algorithm will not add $v$ to $Reach$.

So suppose $u, v \in V(X)$. We know there is such a $u-v$ path by the definition of connectivity. So you can prove by induction that such a path will be found. The proof of correctness Dijkstra's algorithm by induction is a good one to model.

Now consider if $u \in V(X)$ but $v \not \in V(X)$. Suppose the algorithm returns $v \in Reach$. This implies that there is a vertex $i$ with an edge connecting it to $v$ by your if statement in the second for loop. Since $i$ is being traversed, this implies $i$ is reachable from $u$ (ie., there is a $u-i$ path) by our previous inductive argument. And so by extension, there is a $u, v$ path, implying $v$ is part of component $X$. However, as $v \not \in V(X)$, there is no such $u-v$ path by definition of connectivity, a contradiction. Hence, the algorithm will not traverse $v$.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I think this is what I am looking for. So are the invariants I found useless for proving this algorithm, I don't need to prove them?

Comment: Your invariants are nice for breaking down the problem some. I don't think they're the cleanest or most direct way to construct a proof of algorithm correctness, though. You don't need them at this point. Glad I was able to help some!

Comment: Okay great thanks! Is there any place I can go to break down this problem so I can learn how to use these invariants? Also is there a common or popular name for this algorithm?

Comment: Invariants 1 and 3 are used implicitly in the termination portion or the proof. Invariant 2 is a sloppy way of doing the induction. I'd avoid explicitly using them. Your algorithm is a rather bloated breadth first traversal.

Comment: Another question, is V(X) the goal for the output at the completion of this algorithm?

Comment: $V(X)$ is the vertex set of the connected component being traversed. The returned set should contain all of the vertices on said component.